# I can't put two or more svg shapes in my js file and have them show on my website

Tags: javascript, html, svg, geometry, shapes

When I open my html page in a web browser I only can see the first shape in this list, the other shapes don't appear as if there was no code for them.
I wrote the code in two separate files, an html file and a js file.
Can anyone tell me please if there is something missing in my code that is causing that issue to occur.
Code in my html file:
      `
      
      
      Let's make a face with D3.js

```
  </head>
  <body>
  <svg width="1000" height="500"></svg>

  <script src="bundle.js">
  </script>

  </body>
  </html>`
```

Code in my js file :

```
`(function () {
'use strict';

const svg = d3.select('svg');
svg.style('background-color','red');
const height = parseFloat(svg.attr('height'));
const width= +svg.attr('width');

const circle = svg.append('circle');
circle.attr('r', height / 2);
circle.attr('cx', width/2);
circle.attr('cy', height/2);
circle.attr('fill', '#FFFFFF');
circle.attr('stroke', 'green');

const leftEye = svg.append('rect');
rect.attr('x', width/2);
rect.attr('y', height/2);
rect.attr('fill', '#000000');
rect.attr('stroke', 'green');

const rightEye = svg.append('circle');
circle.attr('r', 30);
circle.attr('cx', 600);
circle.attr('cy', height/2);
circle.attr('fill', '#FFFFFF');
circle.attr('stroke', 'green');`
```

Comment: `rect !== leftEye`, `circle !== rightEye` -> voting to close as typo

Comment: @Andrew: And you know why exactly that this is my DV? New member or not, this type of problem won't help future readers hence there's a close option for this exact type of problem ([#2 in the list](https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic)). Feel free to flag my comment if you think this will change anything.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Where you have:

```js
rect.attr('x', width/2);
```

You're confused about the string `'rect'` within `svg.append('rect')`. You shouldn't reference this svg as `rect`. Rather, you've set it to a constant and named it `leftEye`, so you should reference it as `leftEye` instead:

```js
leftEye.attr('x', width/2);
```

And the same goes for the `rightEye` variable.